# JQplot with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, webview, jqplot

I have an android app, in which I am Plotting graphs with [**jqplot**](http://www.jqplot.com/). I am also using [**JQuery Mobile**](http://jquerymobile.com/). Everything works perfect other than a small issue. When I place my chart inside a **div** tag which has **data-role="content"** which is used to determine content with jquery mobile.

The bar chart onlick events give me an unwanted shadows of the bar which is not even at the same co-ordinates as the original bar. I tried googling this issue alot but couldn't find anything that could help me.

Here is my code snippet:

```html
<div data-role="content" class="ui-body" id="android">
  <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'
    valign='top'>
    <tr height="10%">
        <td>
        <div><span>Active Deals: </span><span id="info1">Nothing yet</span></div>
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr height="90%">
        <td  style="width:80%;">
            <div id="chart1" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        </td>
        <td >
            <div id="legend"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
</div>
```

This is how I registered my onlick event:

```js
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',
    function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
        $('#info1').html('series: '+seriesIndex+'
          , point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);}); 
});
```

Here is how the shadow looks on click of bar, notice the disjoint light shaded bars:

[image: Green bar clicked which shows shadow on left]

Just if this can help. I'm doing this inside a webview control of android apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `data-role="content"` with `data-role="none"` so it will not inherit jquery mobile style for that particular div. This should work